# What does the bracket mean in XLA HLO's tensor shape?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I am confused with the number in `{}`. For example, the below code is sample XLA HLO, and I am having trouble understanding what `%bitcast.26` does.

```
%gather.347 = f16[8192,768]{1,0} gather(f16[30522,768]{1,0} %convert.339, s32[8192]{0} %bitcast.25), offset_dims={1}, collapsed_slice_dims={0}, start_index_map={0}, index_vector_dim=1, slice_sizes={1,768}
%bitcast.26 = f16[16,512,768]{2,1,0} bitcast(f16[8192,768]{1,0} %gather.347)
```

Of course, I can see that the dimension changed from `f16[8192,768]{1,0}` to `f16[16,512,768]{2,1,0}`, but I do not get what `{1,0}` and `{2,1,0}` represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square bracket(`[]`): logical dimension.

Curly bracket(`{}`): physical dimension layout that is going to be stored on the device (GPU, CPU, or TPU, whatever).